# Parse Python source for class/function line numbers

Tags: python

I want to parse a Python file and for each line know the line number of the start of the function/method/class that the statement resides in.

The ideal return would be a dictionary with each line number as a key and the value being the line number of the function/class/method that the line of code belongs to.

```
0: def(a):
1:     print 'hi mom'
2:     print 'hello world'
```

Returns:

```
{1: 0
 2: 0}
```

I have been unable to find any valuable information on this problem.  I am contemplating writing some sort of hacky solution that analyzes indentation levels and hacks together the dictionary that I'm looking for.

Comment: the `inspect` module would probably help somewhat ... this is not exactly a trivial problem ... also you may wish to look into `eval` , or if you can get away with it `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to get this information. Essentially, you call `ast.parse()` with your code as input, which gives you an AST object. From there, you can inspect the resulting tree which gives you the line number of every node. You can then create your desired dictionary based on the AST structure.

Comment: Great answer. If you're trying to do this with code in your own project that's been loaded up, you can get the information more easily by just `inspect`ing the live objects, but if you don't need to load the code, `ast` is the way to get it parsed.

Comment: Another one in the list of "ast does this, but I will leave the exercise for the reader" type of answers.  Yes, I already knew ast probably handles this.  Ast is not that trivial to understand, so what do I learn from this answer, besides hearing the ast elevator pitch?